# Soap UI: Failed to find MockResponse

Tags: web-services, soap, soapui

I'm trying to implement a soap mock service using SoapUI (v5.2.1). More specifically,  I want to associate specific soap responses with specific requests. For example:

QUERY_MATCH configuration:

- XPath:

  ```
  declare namespace mynamespace1="http://my.namespace1.com/";

  declare namespace mynamespace2="http://my.namespace2.com/xsd";

  //mynamespace1:myrequest/cmd[1]/mynamespace2:myparam[1]
  ```
- Expected Value:

  ```
   12345
  ```
- Dispatch to:

  ```
   myMockResponse
  ```

Soap Request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:mynamespace1="http://my.namespace1.com/" xmlns:mynamespace2="http://my.namespace2.com">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <mynamespace1:myrequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <cmd>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mynamespace2:id>1</mynamespace2:id>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <mynamespace2:myparam>12345</mynamespace2:myparam>
         </cmd>
      </mynamespace1:myrequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, when I perform this request in SoapUI, I get the following response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <soap:Code>
            <soap:Value>Server</soap:Value>
         </soap:Code>
         <soap:Reason>
            <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
            <soap:Text xml:lang="en">Failed to find MockResponse</soap:Text>
         </soap:Reason>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, I see that you made a typo in your soap request in the declaration of the namespaces:

    xmlns:namespace2

should be :

    xmlns:mynamespace2

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected it. Still it is unrelated to my problem

Comment: Can you create a `QUERY_MATCH` that does work, that routes to a specific mock response? I'm not 100% sure that the "Default Response" on query_match works